# PHP quotes inside quotes

Tags: php, string, escaping, quotes

Is it possible to put quotes inside quotes?

If so how?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

    echo '<span onclick="$(this).addClass('selected');"> </span>';

?>
```

Comment: They're called *quotation marks*, and you need to [*escape*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) them.

Comment: Could you possibly mean quotes?

Answer (score 16):

According to [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

```
To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (\).
```

It means you could have:

```
<?php
  echo '<span onclick="$(this).addClass(\'selected\');"> </span>';
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Heredoc is the perfect solution for this:

```
<?php
echo <<< HereDocString
    <span onclick="$(this).addClass('selected');"> </span>
HereDocString;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
<?php
  // some code
?>

    <span onclick="$(this).addClass('selected');"> </span>

<?php
  // some more code.

?>
```