# Question for quotations issue in PHP code

Tags: php, mysqli

Query failed based on '"' or something else?

I have tried to use '"' or '\"' or '\"'

MySQL code:

```
SELECT Name, Address, City FROM PERSONAL WHERE Name LIKE "A%" INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/output.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

When SQL statement above worked in MySQL command line.  Then I try to convert into PHP coding like this below:

```
$filepath="/tmp/output.csv";
$query = "SELECT Name, Address, City FROM PERSONAL_DATA WHERE Name LIKE "A%" INTO OUTFILE '$filepath' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";

$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die (mysqli_error());
```

Seems to me I have an issue with quotations.
When I use `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`

I tried `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'` or `'\\"'`

The query tests failed. PHP page returned empty and sometimes error comes up in logs for parsing errors.

Comment: For clarification due to readablity issue when I posted this: '"'  this consists of single quote then double quote then single quote.

Comment: You also need to escape the quotes around `"%A"`. Try `$query = "SELECT Name, Address, City FROM PERSONAL_DATA WHERE Name LIKE \"A%\" INTO OUTFILE '$filepath' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";`

Comment: And the error message is ... ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP quotes inside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107329/php-quotes-inside-quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use double quote as the delimiter around the PHP string, you need to escape any double quotes inside the string. You can also use single quotes inside, to avoid having to escape them.

```
$query = "SELECT Name, Address, City FROM PERSONAL_DATA WHERE Name LIKE 'A%' INTO OUTFILE '$filepath' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use single quotes for strings in PHP and escape all the single quotes used inside the string.

```
$filepath = '/tmp/output.csv';
$query = 'SELECT Name, Address, City FROM PERSONAL_DATA WHERE Name LIKE \'A%\' INTO OUTFILE \'' . $filepath . '\' FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\r\n\'';
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
```