# PHP not executing a shell exec command

Tags: php, html

To keep this simple this code works:

> ```
> <?php
> $sinfo = shell_exec('ss -t -r state established');
> echo "<pre>$sinfo</pre>";
> ?>
> ```

And this code code doesn't:

> ```
> <?php
> $sinfo = shell_exec('ss -H -t -r state established | awk '{$1=$2=""; print $0}'');
> echo "<pre>$sinfo</pre>";
> ?>
> ```

Does anyone know how I can get the code that doesn't work to work?

I have ran the command in a normal terminal and they execute as expected, but when ran with PHP it cause a server 500 error - this seems to require a PHP code review from someone more competent than myself.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `ss` might not be available as a command in PHP's context; try `/usr/sbin/ss ...`

Comment: Have a look here: [PHP quotes inside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107329/php-quotes-inside-quotes).

Comment: Yes KIKO thankyou thats the answer :) I needed to escape my single quotes- ill mark as complete

Comment: Ah, no longer confused! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [KIKO Software](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3986005/kiko-software) his link [PHP quotes inside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107329/php-quotes-inside-quotes). had the answer that I needed:

I had to escape the single quotes in the AWK

Working code:

> ```
> <?php
> $sinfo = shell_exec('ss -H -t -r state established | awk \'{$1=$2=""; print $0}\'');
> echo "<pre>$sinfo</pre>";
> ?>
> ```